# What are some good softwares to simulate rocket trajectories ?

Tags: rockets, software, sounding-rocket, trajectory

I am working on a college project which is based upon a experimental sounding rocket and it would be really helpful if the community could refer me good softwares to simulate trajectories of a rocket.

Comment: You can try http://openrocket.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sprinkle a little Runge-Kutta on your favorite language and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

The principal software that I found (and free) is the ["Comprehensive General-Purpose Simulation of Attitude and Trajectory Dynamics and Control of Multiple Spacecraft Composed of Multiple Rigid or Flexible Bodies"](https://software.nasa.gov/software/GSC-16720-1) from the NASA Technology Tranfer program. [More alternatives](https://software.nasa.gov/search/software/trajectory) in the same catalog:

Answer (score 1):

OpenRocket is free based on JAVA runtime. I have personally used this. So long so good. http://openrocket.info/

RockSim is a paid version.
RAS Aero is an other option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can specify a custom rocket and flight plan in [flightclub.io](https://www2.flightclub.io/)

The examples below give you some idea of how it works. The big image is the first launch of the Falcon Heavy, you can see the two side boosters land on the left and the center booster over the horizon on the right.

Here are some example images found on the following pages. The developer of the site can be reached through the site and is also an occasional visiter here: [@DeclanMurphy](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/21025/declan-murphy)

- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20275/12102) to *What is this debris on the CRS-10 reentry at T6:30?*
- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24923/12102) to *What is the velocity profile of a Falcon 9 first stage landing?*
- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26719/12102) to *How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?*
- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27233/12102) to *Understanding Flightclub.io simulation of SpaceX's Bangabandhu launch*

[image: flightclub.io Camera Tools view]

[image: flightclub.io]

[image: flightclub.io]

Answer (score 0):

For a free download of a Rocket trajectory design and analysis program, go to this web page: http://trajectorysolution.com/zoom%20program.html

The ZOOM program works with Windows operating systems and is used for the conceptual design and analysis of rockets and their missions.