# How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?

Tags: flightclub

A comment on [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26594/12102) by Flight Club website developer Declan Murphy says

> I've actually added tools specifically for photographers. Click on "Camera Tools" under the top-left hamburger menu on those pages to set your own coordinates, elevation, FoV, aspect ratio, etc, to see how the launch trajectory will appear from your position. [Here's an example of my own view](https://www.flightclub.io/result?code=FHD1&tab=2&lat=28.4064608&lon=-80.6175608&z=25&fov=90) of the Falcon Heavy Test Flight.

When I click the link, I see the view, but it's not clear how to set up/define a new photo shoot.

How are the photographer's coordinates and viewing direction be defined in the program? Are there places to enter the camera FOV, or image format size and lens focal length in order to generate simulated views like the one in the link?

Screenshot of link, click for full size:

[image: Flight Club Camera Tools view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh hey, that's me.

You see the hamburger menu in the top-left of the trajectory view?

[image]

Clicking that gives you a menu from which to choose Camera Tools.

[image]

This opens a dialog box to enter your coordinates & camera settings

[image]

If any photographers stumble across this and want more customization, let me know and I can add things in. I don't know much about photography, what's there currently is just what one photographer on r/SpaceX requested!

P.S. There may be a small CSS bug in there at the moment. Sometimes the hamburger menu is not clickable, but if you move to a different tab and then come back to "3D View", that fixes it :)

Comment: Aha! I think I'd clicked the *wrong hamburger* when I'd tried it before. This is great!

Comment: @uhoh Cool, glad to help :) Let me know if you want any more customization. Also, correct answer? :)

Comment: I have a hunch this answer is indeed correct. Sometimes people wait a few days to accept; the action triggers a bump in activity, increasing the potential visibility for the answer.

Comment: [Does anyone know how the Flight Club website simulates Falcon 9 launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30914/12102) has been asked.