# Is there a website with launch paths/visible regions?

Tags: reference-request, visibility-of-spacecraft, launch-trajectories

Last night's Space-X launch led to [excitement from observers in locations that don't typically see the upper atmosphere effects](https://www.newson6.com/story/61f8aacbeb119d0728056cb8/what-was-that-spiral-in-the-oklahoma-sky-aliens), prompting a lot of questions about it and when other such launches can be seen.  I know that the launch [was a rarer southerly launch trajectory from Cape Canaveral](https://www.clickorlando.com/news/local/2022/01/31/coast-guard-starts-investigation-of-royal-caribbean-ship-that-caused-spacex-scrub/), and so I am guessing that the locations to see the upper atmosphere display may have been different than is typical.  I know there are lists of [Florida launches](https://spacecoastlaunches.com/launch-list/) and [plenty](https://in-the-sky.org/satmap_radar.php?year=2022&month=2&day=1) of [satellite tracker sites](https://maps.esri.com/rc/sat2/index.html).  But I have not been able to find sites detailing upcoming individual launch trajectories and perhaps going so far as to suggest viewable locations of such upper atmospheric shows.  Do any options exist?

Answer (score 3):

[FlightClub.io](https://flightclub.io/) is very user friendly and its core (free) simulator tool is useful for seeing where the rocket is going. [Professional launch photographers use Flight Club](https://twitter.com/trevormahlmann/status/1357227953898274821). The [paid subscription](https://flightclub.io/pricing/photography-toolkit) to Flight Club offers many more features, but I don't think it goes as far as *suggesting* viewing locations or predicting the [twilight phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_phenomenon).

Comment: [How can Flightclub.io Camera Tools be used to simulate launch photography geometry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26686/12102) has some related info